# Java to C migration

Tags: java, c, migration

I have to convert a program that is running in Java to C and I am facing some difficulties.

1. What is the best way to transform the Java interfaces into C? I also have classes that implement these interfaces. How should I convert the classes in C code so they would still have a connection with the corresponding interfaces?
2. What would be an equivalence of reflection from Java to C?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are porting code from Java to *C*, you will not have the benefit of explicit object orientation. Are you actually rewriting it in C++?

Comment: I know that I do not benefit of OOP in C, this is why I asked this questions. I have the convert the code from Java to C, so I can't use C++ or other object-oriented programming languages.

Comment: Wow, good luck with that.  Does the java app use a lot of OOP features?

Comment: Interfaces, classes, inheritance, polymorphism, reflection...

Comment: I would think memory management would be your hardest problem. Faking garbage collection in a C program is not an easy task.  All the rest of your questions seem to be about data structures.  C can certainly be used to simulate anything Java does; I'd be surprised if JVMs weren't largely coded in C.   What is the purpose of this conversion?

Comment: Reflection is about what descriptions of the compiled code the "compiler" has left around to be interrogated at runtime.  To offer similar facilities in a C program, you'll have to have data structures that describe the shape of your simulated classes, and record descriptions of the arguments of  your simulated methods, and some way to look up this information.    If you are really trying to replicate *all* this Java functionality, you're in for a rough ride.

Comment: I think the main principle is let struct replace class, and function pointer replace member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. C is not object oriented, so there is no classes. You will have to convert your Java classes into working procedural functions, and use of the `struct` type will help you to encapsulate your class variables.
2. You might try C++ since you could most likely port most of your Java class objects to C++ with little effort. If you do decide to use C++, you can also learn the std, & boost libraries which will support most of the functionality that you will find in your Java APIs.
3. If you plan to recreate the GUI I'd suggest you look into cross platform GUI APIs, something like GTK+ which will work with both C and C++, or Qt which is a C++ API and has its own IDE which is very nice. Otherwise, you will have to learn the Windows/Unix/Mac/etc APIs in order to make your own GUIs.

Hope this helps,

-Dave

Comment: 1. I tried to use structures with function pointers as an equivalent to interfaces and classes. And I finished to have struct in struct for the classes that implement interfaces and extend other classes. But I find it quite difficult to access variables defined in the class struct from functions defined in the interfaces struct. Any ideas?

Comment: Oooh yeah, I wouldn't put function pointers in the struct, I would just encapsulate necessary variables inside of it and use outside functions to manipulate the variables as needed.

Comment: Pass the ptr of the struct containing the necessary variables to the functions. Probably not the most desired solution, but I'm not sure if there is any other way in C.

Comment: In order to access the variables inside struct, I have to pass the struct to the function or only the variables needed...but to do this, I have to change the prototype of the original function from the interface. And I don't want to do that, as I would need to change the function for every different class that implements that interface. I also thought of defining a different function corresponding to the one in the interface in every class implementing the interface, but would it be correct?

Comment: Well, the functions & structs way would be the most standard way to do it, and you'd only have to add one more argument to each function which would be the ptr to the struct. If you put the desired struct in a global variable you could essentially do it without having to change the prototypes but you would have to set the global variable to the ptr of the struct you want to change before calling the functions. Sort of a ... context system. Set the context before calling the functions.

Comment: I have all these structs in header files and the body of the functions in the corresponding source file. I will try to use global variables in order to keep to code kind of simple. Thank you.